# Error with my site when viewed on a mobile device, the html seems to keep getting a :before issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, web, mobile

For some reason when I use my website on a mobile device the stucture keeps on changing, although everything seems to be working fine, my menu button works, but if you try to scroll

I thought it might be a problem with the js but it doesnt seem to be

you can see it on https://diegoasgportfolio.com/lapizzeria/#

Comment: I checked out the site on both mobile and desktop. What's the exact issue that you're facing? 
The only issue that I see on the mobile is, the navigation closes when scrolling. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes that is the issue I am talking about